# Why this map function is receiving object not string in react. I need to use item.item to render a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to add this simple todo item string in the array which works but when i am using it in map and render it I need to use item.item for it to work, if I use item only i am receiving an error of objecs are not valid as React Child...Btw this is with redux.how can i fix this?

here is the Lists Display

```
const todos=useSelector(state=>state)
 <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>note</th>
            <th>remove</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        {
            todos.map(item=>(
                <List item={item}/>
            ))
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

here is the list item:

```
    <tr>
    <td>{item.item}</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
```

here is how i add it

```
const AddList=()=>{
const [newItem,setNewItem]=useState("")
const dispatch=useDispatch()
const handleAdder=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(addItem(newItem))
}

return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={(e)=>handleAdder(e)}>
    <input value={newItem} onChange={(e)=>setNewItem(e.target.value)}></input>
    <button type="submit">add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}
```

here is the reducer

```
const todoReducer=(state=[],action)=>{

    switch(action.type){
        case('ADD_ITEM'):
        return [...state,action.newItem]
        default:{
            return state
        }
        
    }
}
export default todoReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

because todos is array of object if you don't want to use item.item just use object destructing like this :

```
 <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>note</th>
            <th>remove</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        {
            todos.map(item=>(
                <List {...item} key={item.id}/>
            ))
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

this will pass all object keys as props for the child component.

don't forget to add `key` for map method on each component.